# how to use MDX average function?

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I am VERY new to mdx, and about to learn it. i got into trouble right now ,because i want to get average amount for each weekday between two dates. 
For example between 1st of november and 1st of december there are 4 mondays, so average would be [Measures].[Amount] / 4, but i really cant figure out how to express this simple function in MDX

```
    with  member [Measures].[Avg] as
                    avg([Dim Date].[Day Of Week].[Day Of Week]
                     , [Measures].[amount])

 SELECT NON EMPTY { ([Measures].[Avg]), ([Measures].[Amount])} ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY { ([Dim Date].[Day Of Week].[Day Of Week].ALLMEMBERS  * [Dim Date].[Date Int].[Date Int].ALLMEMBERS )} 
  ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dim Client].[Common Client UID].&[{xx}] } ) 
                         ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( [Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20151115] : [Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20151215] )
                         ON COLUMNS FROM [ff])) 
                         WHERE ( [Dim Client].[Common Client UID].&[{xx}] )
```

This query give me each weekday and all the dates which are bound to the specific weekday, and for each date there are an total amount.

[image]
like you can see my average is the same as total. I thought that i could just select all the weekdays between two date, find out for example how many mondays there are and divide it number with amount. but i couldnt figure that out either.

```
    with  member [Measures].[avg] as
                    avg([Dim Date].[Day Of Week].[Day Of Week],  [Measures].[Amount])



 SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[avg], [Measures].[Amount]} ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Dim Date].[Day Of Week].[Day Of Week].ALLMEMBERS  )} 
  ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dim Client].[Common Client UID].&[{xx}] } ) 
                         ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( [Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20151115] : [Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20151215] )
                         ON COLUMNS FROM [ff])) 
                         WHERE ( [Dim Client].[Common Client UID].&[{xx}] )
```

result :

[image]

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is average amount over the dates corresponding to that weekday for the given date range.

You can just move the date range to the definition of calculated member, so that when value for a particular weekday is evaluated, the date range is also considered.

```
with  member [Measures].[Avg] as
avg
  (
   [Dim Date].[Day Of Week].CURRENTMEMBER * {[Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20151115] : [Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20151215]}
   ,[Measures].[amount]
  )

 SELECT NON EMPTY { ([Measures].[Avg]), ([Measures].[Amount])} ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY [Dim Date].[Day Of Week].[Day Of Week].ALLMEMBERS * [Dim Date].[Date Int].[Date Int].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS 
 FROM [ff]
 WHERE ( [Dim Client].[Common Client UID].&[{xx}] )
```

Comment: That makes sense. But if i run the query i get : CellOrdinal 1
VALUE #Error Query (4, 5) The CURRENTMEMBER function expects a hierarchy expression for the 1 argument. A member expression was used.
FORMATTED_VALUE #Error Query (4, 5) The CURRENTMEMBER function expects a hierarchy expression for the 1 argument. A member expression was used.

Comment: query can execute now, but there are no results.

Comment: ok, try again, i just skimmed off unnecessary MDX in the code,

Comment: i think somethign is wrong with the cube it self, because my previouse queries doesnt show anythin either. Thank you for your help

Comment: One little thing, right now i am getting All the dates there are, not only the span which is defined in measures.avg

Comment: ah, fixed it by adding span to the select on rows